# In C#, How can I create satellite resource that will be used at design time?

Tags: c#, localization

I am trying to localize an application, but I have a couple restrictions.  I must use Resx-based localization (I cannot use LocBaml).  Also, all resources, including the fallback resource (en-US), must be stored in a satellite assembly.  No resources can be embedded with the application.

Here's my problem.  Every time I add a string, I must add it to Resources.resx and then add the same string to the fallback resource, Resources.en-US.resx.  If I understand it correctly, the Resources.resx file is used at compile/design time, while the Resources.en-US.resx files ends up being the one used at runtime.  Is there any way around this?  Can I somehow link the two so that only one file will need to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple pre-Build action that copies your default .resx file(s) to the en-US version? I seem to remember that the culture-codes are not recorded inside, so a simple Copy File would do.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to have an identical fallback resource? When you are done with the primary one (for the default language), just copy the `resx`-file to a new file.

Comment: Everything compiles great when putting all my strings in the default Resources.resx file.  But, exceptions are thrown at runtime because it is looking for the satellite resource (Resource.en-US.resx).  Most people would embed the default/fallback resource into the main assembly and this problem wouldn't occur.  Unfortunately, I have been told not to so that the resources can be updated later without having to recompile the entire app.  I could do the whole design now and copy later.  But, this would still cause headaches for other developers when editing the form.